# Ruby on rails forms: How to put text into an input field that disappears on click

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I want to create a form that does not have a label, and instead puts the directions inside the actual input text field. I also want the directions to disappear when you click the text field.

Here is an example 
http://www.dailyblogtips.com/wp-content/uploads/searchform.png

I know in html, you do something like this

```
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="Text to be displayed here" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
```

But how can I accomplish this using rails form helpers.

Here is what I have so far

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      <div class="panel">
        <%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>
            <%= f.label :body, "Description" %>
            <%= f.text_area :body %>
            <%= f.submit 'Create message', class: 'button small secondary' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd give the placeholder attribute a try, it'll only work with newer browsers but there are a few jQuery libraries that will automatically detect the ones that don't support it and perform more or less the same thing that your javscript snippet is doing. Here is an example of using the placeholder field:

```
<%= f.text_field :field_name, :placeholder => "Disappearing Text" %>
```

**Edit:** Here is a solid jQuery fallback plugin:

http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Answer (score 0):

In html, the pre-text in an input is called the `placeholder` attribute.

You can add that attribute into `form_for` looped fields like so:

```
<%= f.text_field :some_data, :placeholder => "value" %>
```

BUT, when doing the placeholder attribute, beware that its not completely supported across older versions of some browsers. So often some JS is required to polyfil this functionality...you should care about supporting this if you don't use traditional labels next to your input fields.